# How can I compare two columns against one column in excel 2016?

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
ColumnA Receipt# Column B       
Mark    188      Robert
Pat     353      Susan
Robert  234      Sulia
Heidi   764      Mark
Sharon  123      Heidi
Sulia   908      Pat
Susan   345      Sharon
```

Column A is the exact way how all the rows must be. I cannot change the order of the rows for column A. However the receipt numbers correspond to the names in column B. As you can see the names in Column A and B are identical. I am seeking to see the following:

```
ColumnA  Receipt#   
Mark     764
Pat      908
Robert   188
Heidi    123
Sharon   345
Sulia    234
Susan    353
```

Comment: ColumnA Receipt# Column B  
Mark        188        Robert
Pat         353        Susan
Robert 234        Sulia
Heidi 764       Mark
Sharon 123       Heidi
Sulia 908       Pat
Susan 345       Sharon

Column A is the exact way how all the rows must be. I cannot change the order of the rows for column A. However the receipt numbers correspond to the names in column B. As you can see the names in Column A and B are identical. I am seeking to see the following:

Column A Receipt # 
Mark          764
Pat          908
Robert 188
Heidi 123
Sharon 345
Sulia 234
Susan 353

Comment: I have tried to enter a table of what I am looking for, but I am not able to do it. I keeps showing it just like a word document. I can provide a sample of what I am looking for if somebody is interested in helping me. Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

- Insert a column between 1st and 2nd column where you want the matching receipt numbers to the first column
- In the new column, go to second row (i.e. first name entry - Mark) and enter the INDEX-MATCH formula as below: `=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A2,D:D,0),)`
- Copy this and paste through to the last cell in this column and formula references will update automatically

Attached pic shows the end result:
[image]

Comment: @fixer1234, I re-read the problem, it says that "Column A is the exact way how all rows must be". This is not great English, but if I try to read what Dina wants to do here is to maintain the sort order of the values in Column A. My answer conforms to this requirement. Also, kindly note that my idea is to help Dina with a way to go about solving this problem rather than spoon feeding, if she still needs further help I am happy to help her out.

Comment: thank you for your response. The formula did work for the example given, but the actual list of over 3k names has not only duplicates, but also names that appear 3 and 4 times. Therefore there are names with 2, 3 and 4 receipts numbers. In another words, the formula did not work for the actual data. I will send a sample of the data later. thanks again for helping me. Dina

Comment: @DinaMar, hmmm! Maybe you can clarify your question with the scenario you have mentioned and the expected format in which you are trying to collate/present the 2, 3 or 4 receipt numbers. Without knowing that we have to assume certain things while proposing the answers. Also, if you have tried an approach but not quite there, then do share the approach that you are working on

Comment: Column A     Receipt # Column B
mark             458          robert
pat             253          susan
pat             254          peter
robert     781          mark
heidi             256          heidi
sharon     789          pat
sharon     790          sharon
sharon     791 
sharon     792 
peter      256 
peter      257 
susan      347

Comment: the below is the desired result:

Comment: continuation: Column B must show the receipt numbers from Receipt # column. You tackled that portion with the provided formula, now how to achieved the result? I understand I will have to merge cell, so that I can show multiple receipts numbers for one name. Once I merge rows the formula does not work anymore. This project has over 3k names, and Column A shows one name more than one time and different receipt numbers. I've done so much of cleaning on this data regarding deleting middle initials at the end.